# JUnit 5 - Entity created but not being retrieve

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm testing a method from service class which basically calls the method `save` from my repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface GameManagerRepository extends JpaRepository<Game, String> {

    Game findCreateGameByPublisherId(String publisherId);
}
```

This is my test method:

```
    @DisplayName("Test for createGame")
    @Test
    public void createGameTest(){
        game = new Game();
        game.setPublisherId("123");
        game.setGameDataId("abc");
        game.setName("hello world");
        gameManagerRepository.save(game);
        System.out.println(game);
        System.out.println(game != null);
        System.out.println(gameManagerRepository.findCreateGameByPublisherId("123"));
    }
```

I did put some `System.out.println` to try to identify what exactly is wrong wiht my code and this is the result:

```
Game(gameDataId=abc, publisherId=123, name=hello world, timePlayed=null)
true
null
```

As you can see, I could not find the entity in the database and I can't find out why.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What annotations do you have on your test class?

Comment: @tgdavies for now, only ```@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)```.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's not clear how you create the repository.

Comment: Sorry, @daniu but your comment makes no sense at all. I added all necessary info and the code as well. Or do you want the controller method as well as service method?

Comment: As @daniu said, please show how the `gameManagerRepository` is created in your unit test. You say "I'm testing a method from service class", but I don't see any service class mentioned in your test, just the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Since you state in the comments that you use `MockitoExtension` but don't specify how exactly you create the repository, I'm going to have to assume that this is what you do:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RepositoryTest {

    @Mock
    private GameManagerRepository gameManagerRepository;

    @DisplayName("Test for createGame")
    @Test
    public void createGameTest(){
        game = new Game();
        game.setPublisherId("123");
        game.setGameDataId("abc");
        game.setName("hello world");
        gameManagerRepository.save(game);
        System.out.println(game);
        System.out.println(game != null);
        System.out.println(gameManagerRepository.findCreateGameByPublisherId("123"));
    }
}
```

The answer is that method calls for mocked instances always return `null` if you didn't mock the call beforehand (eg `when(repo.findCreate(any())).thenReturn(game)`).

This answer is correct but somewhat tongue in cheek to show you why it's important to show how the repository is created.

You probably want to create a Spring test (`@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)`) to fire up the Spring context and test the actual beans.